# Heap space OutOfMemoryError: available vs. requested

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark application which ran into OutOfMemory Error.The GC log is as follows. Is there a way I can tell how much memory was requested and how much memory was available at the time of request? Thank you!

```
3429.458: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3495918K->3495908K(6990848K)] [ParOldGen: 2096
9872K->20969870K(20971520K)] 24465790K->24465778K(27962368K), [Metaspace: 56727K->56723K(1101824K)]
, 0.4597426 secs] [Times: user=0.90 sys=0.01, real=0.46 secs] 
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 16095"...
os::fork_and_exec failed: Cannot allocate memory (12)
3429.990: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 3495936K->3495906K(6990848K)] [ParOldGen: 20969937K->20969933K(20971520K)] 24465873K->24465840K(27962368K), [Metaspace: 56723K->56723K(1101824K)], 5.4942216 secs] [Times: user=34.79 sys=0.58, real=5.50 secs] 
3435.485: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 3495936K->3495907K(6990848K)] [ParOldGen: 20969933K->20969933K(20971520K)] 24465869K->24465840K(27962368K), [Metaspace: 56723K->56723K(1101824K)], 2.3213689 secs] [Times: user=14.01 sys=0.22, real=2.32 secs] 
3437.823: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 3495936K->3495908K(6990848K)] [ParOldGen: 20970002K->20969998K(20971520K)] 24465938K->24465907K(27962368K), [Metaspace: 56723K->56723K(1101824K)], 0.4090566 secs] [Times: user=0.83 sys=0.01, real=0.40 secs]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can tell how much memory was requested

Not from the information provided.  Possibly not at all.

> and how much memory was available at the time of request?

According to the GC log, this is when you ran out of memory:

```
3429.458: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 
           [PSYoungGen: 3495918K->3495908K(6990848K)] 
           [ParOldGen: 20969872K->20969870K(20971520K)] 
           24465790K->24465778K(27962368K), 
           [Metaspace: 56727K->56723K(1101824K)], 0.4597426 secs] 
          [Times: user=0.90 sys=0.01, real=0.46 secs]
```

This `24465790K->24465778K(27962368K)` line says that:

- space used before GC 24465790K
- space used after  GC 24465778K
- heap space after  GC 27962368K

So it looks like 3496590K is free out of 27962368K.

(The other triples can be read the same way ...)

It looks like the old generation is full.  I suspect the GC failure is due to the GC being unable to tenure objects from eden space because of that.   Also note that neither the young or old generation collectors managed to free much memory, and neither did the Full GC.

So the overall diagnosis is that your heap is full.  For some reason the allocator could not put the new object into eden space.  It might have been larger than the available free space in eden, or it might have been bigger than the large object threshold.

Comment: I am just curious. Why jvm cannot show the amount of request memory when throwing OOM exception? This is a very useful information.

Comment: 1) Check the OpenJDK source code to satisfy your curiosity.  2) If after your investigation you think it should be different, submit a feature request ... or a patch.